# Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; special characters

Tags: php, database

I am doing php and writing some code to insert data into different tables at the same time. I wrote a foreach loop and one part of my code is as follows:

```
 while ($datarow = dbgetrow($dataresult)) {
                    if ( $dotcount > $datanumrows) {
                            showarchivestatus(" .", true);
                            $dotcount = 1;
                    }
                    $sqlvalues = "";
```

Comment: more code: 
                        $sqlvalues = "";
                        foreach($lu_cols as $lu_col) {
                                if ($datarow[$lu_col] == "") {
                                    $sqlvalues = $sqlvalues.", NULL ";
                                } else {
                                        $sqlvalues = $sqlvalues.", \"".makesafe($datarow[$lu_col])."\"";
                                }
                        }

Comment: Add this into question

Comment: You should use prepared queries, then you won't run into problems like this.

Comment: If not, you need to escape your strings. That needs to be done in the code that creates `$sqlvalues`.

Comment: @devpro `htmlentities` is for encoding strings in HTML, it has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: @Kyan Add that code to the question, not a comment. The problem is apparently in `makesafe`, it's not escaping backslashes properly.

Comment: @barmar escape the string is good... And one more thing OP using connection inside the function

Comment: @Barmar@devpro Thank you, I will add more code and post the makesafe function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your string before putting it into the database.

Here is a basic example of how to do it in MySQLi

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is an example of PDO:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('sqlite:/home/lynn/music.sql3');

/* Dangerous string */
$string = 'Naughty \' string';
print "Unquoted string: $string\n";
print "Quoted string:" . $conn->quote($string) . "\n";
?>
```

You may want to consider using a prepared statement. There are several benefits to this including:

1. Security - Helps prevent SQL injection
2. Speed - You only are sending the values.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Sources:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: thank you, but I am thinking about the problem is apparently in makesafe, it's not escaping backslashes properly, which @Barmar mentioned above. I am trying to use  $text = str_replace("\", "\\", $text);