# How to insert Quotes into database

Tags: php, mysql

My original question: [insert special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661090/invalid-query-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-special-characters)

I want to insert the """ into database with php, and I use the function to escape the quotes:

```
$text = str_replace("\"","\\\"",$text);
```

my original data is:

```
"support.apple.com/kb/HT4070"
```

but when I check my database it shows:

```
\"support.apple.com/kb/HT4070\"
```

and I want to keep this quote, how can I do it in the php? Thank you very much.

Comment: try this `'"support.apple.com/kb/HT4070"'`

Comment: show the code where you are updating your table with this information. You may do this by clicking the _"edit"_ link on your original question.

Answer (score 4):

Never do this directly. You can have a [SQL Injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

If you use PDO, use place hodlders:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO texts (text) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->execute([$text]);
```

Optionally you can also encode the quotes and other bad characters with:

```
$text4db = htmlentities($text);
```

By using placeholders you can directly save quoted strings to the database and retrieve it later as you saved them.

In example:

```
$text = 'My "text" has "quotes"';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO texts (text) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->execute([$text]);
// later
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT text FROM texts LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute([$text]);
$text = $stmt->fetchColumn();
// now $text has the same text: 'My "text" has "quotes"'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't use PDO, and this is a internal website in my company, I just want to use the simple way to insert the quote.

Answer (score 0):

For filter in MySQL use mysql_escape_string.

In your way use like this.

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

But this function is deprecated in new versions of PHP. If you using new versions of php read this article.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: Hi, thank you, and my php version is 5.5.9, is it fine for using mysql_real_escape_string($text)?

Comment: Hello after php 5.5.0 mysql_real_escape_string was deprecated. And for this reccomended use mysql- or pdo connectors.

Answer (score 0):

The right way I found is:

```
$text = str_replace("\\","\\\\",$text);   // this code changes \ to \\
$text = str_replace("\\\"", "\"",$text);  // this code changes  \" to "
```