# How to INSERT quotes into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is a similar to [How to insert Quotes into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798567/how-to-insert-quotes-into-database). However, the answer does not correct my problem.

I have a variable:

```
$font="font-family:Arial,\"Helvetica Neue\",Helvetica,sans-serif;";
```

I want $font to be INSERTED into mysql Database, but all that is inserted:

```
"font-family:Arial,"
```

I need the quotes inserted to recognize the data. How do I go about inserting all of the data?

Comment: How does the linked question *not* correct your problem?  It shows exactly how to use query parameters.

Comment: When you have quotes in the query, you are likely to close the string. Closing it makes everything outside of the quotes be interpreted. That's basically called [SQL-Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Now, even if it's not a successful injection (maybe accidental), it **is** an injection. That is fixed using prepared statements and binding the values. How do you do that? Well, the dup link answers that..

Comment: Maybe you can scape the quotes, there's [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687866/escaping-single-quote-in-php-when-inserting-into-mysql) regarding this topic.